# How to make only one enemy attack player at a time in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In my Scene i have three enemies spawned at a point when player comes in their range they start attacking but the problem is all three enemies are attacking player at the same time. I want that when an enemy attack player other 2 must wait until first one is finished or enemy attack player alternatively

Comment: Set a being attacked by variable so if that’s you you can if it’s not you can’t and if it’s null it’s up for grabs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to assigning a boolean to the player, `isUnderAttack`. When an enemy tries to engage the player, check if the player is under attack, if it is true, stop the attack, if false, go ahead and attack. You can define any type of behavior for queued enemies.

Comment: But how can i stop other enemies to attack player . What if i say that Enemy which reached player first can attack first

Comment: @MeerAzmaanAli You would first check if isUnderAttack true, if it is not, then an enemy attacks, and it is set to true. Therefore, every frame you would check if isUnderAttack and if it is true, you wouldn't do anything.